# CakePHP3 shows date with one hour difference

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP3 framework. In my MySQL database I have a datetime field. In this I have, for example this datetime: 2016-02-10 15:30:51. When I catch this field from CakePHP, I get the correct date time, because if I do a "var_dump()" I got:

```
 object(Cake\I18n\Time)[326]
  public 'date' => string '2016-02-10 15:30:51' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Buenos_Aires' (length=20)
```

But if I do

```
<?= $object->datetime_field ?>
```

I got: '2016-02-10 16:30:51' . It is the same datetime but with one hour plus than the stored in MySQL and the displayed with var_dump()... why? The timezone is correct.

Comment: var_dump looks at the innards of the object. `<?=` is basically `<?php echo`, which means that the objects's magic __toString() function was called, and the output of that may/may not have ANYTHING to do with what you see in the var_dump.

Comment: Ok, and how can understand why the date is printed with one hour difference?

Comment: never looked at cake's innards. could be it's storing things internally in (say) utc, and then uses the `timezone` field to convert to "local" time for output.

Answer (score 0):

var dump shows you the contents of a variable (an object). When you echo an Cake\I18n\Time object it automatically sets the timezone to the timezone of Cake PHP. The timezone of the object is 'America/Buenos_Aires' CakePHP might have a different timezone.

*You can change the default timezone of cakephp in config/bootstrap.php*

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

*You can change the timezone of an Cake\I18n\Time object*

```
$object->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
```

Read more about cake the Cake\I18n\Time Class here:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#dates